# What is the fastest way to search for anagrams?

Tags: php, mysql, anagram

I have a MySQL table with 267,751 words. I try to find the quickest way to find anagrams, without having to search through the entire table for each search, which would be incredibly inefficient.

For the sake of clarity: An anagram is a word that has been put together by changing the order of the letters of another word.

I came up with a method where I created a new column, where the letters in all the words are sorted alphabetically. Before I do a search, I sort the letters in the search word alphabetically, and search in the new column. This method turns out to be quite fast for exact anagrams (words with the same number of letters).

The problem is not finding exact anagrams. But to find anagrams you can make with one letter less, two letters less, three letters less, and all the way down to two letters. There are suddenly many combinations, and an average search time takes around 0,5 seconds which is bad.

There are many anagram search engines out there, so this should not be difficult, but I cannot come up with an effective way to do it. Does anyone have any ideas? How do they manage to do that so quickly?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure there's any efficient way to do this in MySQL.

Comment: In fact, it sounds like it would be difficult to do efficiently in any language/DB. It doesn't seem like there's any way to create an index that optimizes this.

Comment: so you have a word like `barb` and you are trying to find all the words in your database that have at least one a, at least one r, and at least two b's?  is that correct?  If not, please be a lot more specific about what you are trying to do

Comment: It sounds exceedingly difficult to me. Jet Sank. Abandon Elk.

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename;` and show the query you are using that gets your average search time of 0,5 seconds

Comment: Seems like a code golf question https://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could apply Levenstein distance to the presorted strings

Comment: Sometimes it is best to meet a problem halfway instead of head-on.  See my Answer.

Comment: Levenstein is costly to compute over a large number of strings.  Soundex is miserable when matching long words.

Comment: @ysth Correct. Although your word "BARB" does not seem to have any exact anagrams. If we take for example the word "BOOK", you get the exact anagrams BOKO and KOBO, 3-letter anagrams: BOK, KOB, OBO and BOO, 2-letter anagrams: OK, KO, OB, BO and OO. Many word games accept up to fifteen letters, and "Spelling Bee" by The York Times accept 28 letters, so you can imagine all the combinations. I'm using this wordlist: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jesstess/Scrabble/master/scrabble/sowpods.txt).

Comment: @JonAtleSandbakken ah, so opposite of what I said; you have the word book and you want to find from the database bok, kob, obo, boo, etc?  not have the work book and want to find boiko, boko, booky, etc

Comment: @ysth I want it to find all anagrams. Words with same length and smaller words. So, I want the letters BKOO (or organized in any other way) to find all the words in the word list; BOOK, BOKO and KOBO. Of course, to make it more complicated, if the search word is "BKOO*" with a star sign as wild card, it should find BOOKY and other 5-letter words, and "BKOO**" should find 6-letter words ets. But most searches are without wild cards.

Comment: with the wildcards added, this really makes no sense to do in sql.  load all the words in your program and just search them.

Comment: @TylerMiles - A regexp golf:  https://alf.nu/RegexGolf

Comment: Smells like a Scrabble helper?

Comment: @RickJames Yes.

Comment: @JonAtleSandbakken - For Scrabble, using only the given letters is useful only for the very first word.  Perhaps a useful subset of the Question is to find all words of 7+ letters that include all of the given 7 letters ("going out").

Comment: @JonAtleSandbakken - You might enjoy the card game "Royalty".  (And the cards are pretty.)

Comment: @TylerMiles - Thanks.  My first pass over the tasks in RegexGolf was humbling.

Answer (score 2):

The **first step** is simple and very efficient, as you mentioned.

Build a table with 2 (or more) columns:

```
word VARCHAR(..),
sorted VARCHAR(..),
PRIMARY KEY(word),
INDEX(sorted)
```

`sorted` is has the letters of `word`, but sorted.  For example, with 'post':

```
post -- opst
stop -- opst
pots -- opst
spot -- opst
```

That is, this will find all the anagrams:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(word) 
    FROM anagrams
    WHERE sorted = ?
```

when you provide the letters sorted.

For 'rat':

```
art -- art  -- Notice that the `word` == `sorted` in one case
rat -- art
tar -- art
```

The **second step** is tricker...

Expand that `sorted` column into a simple `misspelled` column by deleting one letter:

```
opst -- pst
opst -- ost
opst -- opt
opst -- ops
```

This is a technique for discovering misspellings of these types:

- One letter dropped
- One letter added
- Adjacent pair of letters transposed

In this case, you need to say

```
WHERE misspell IN ('opst', 'pst', 'ost', 'opt', 'ops')
```

And, of course, `INDEX(misspell)`

(Details left as an exercise.)

The **third step** is more of the same -- shorter and shorter strings in the `IN`.

(Again, details left as an exercise.)

Comment: So each word would have multiple rows with all the different misspell possibilities?  for post: o, p, s, t, op, os, ot, ps, pt, st, ops, opt, ost, pst, opst?  that gets big; dichlorodiphenyltrichloroethane would require 3110399 rows

Comment: @ysth - Either big, or requires multiple passes -- checking one char shorter each time.  (I am finding the specifications in this question to be unwieldy.)  After all, perhaps 50K words in that list have "E" in them.

Comment: @ysth - Well, if this is aimed at Scrabble, then 7 is the word limit size for a standalone word and 15(?) is the limit for the wildcard version.

Comment: what is the point of misspeled column? a) if you have a word BOOK then sorted is BKOO no need to add another column misspeled where you remove one letter - b) moreover it makes more combinations so you can't put it in column and c) you put the combinbations in the condition anyway so the sorted column can be used for this? i am missing the idea of misspeled column

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just storing a new column with letters sorted alphabetically, have a new column with a like expression, with the letters sorted alphabetically and a % before and after and between different letters, like:

| word | word_like |
| --- | --- |
| b | %b% |
| bk | %b%k% |
| bo | %b%o% |
| boko | %b%k%o%o% |
| boo | %b%o%o% |
| book | %b%k%o%o% |
| k | %k% |
| kb | %b%k% |
| ko | %k%o% |
| kob | %b%k%o% |
| o | %o% |
| ob | %b%o% |
| ok | %k%o% |

and use it for your search:

```
select word from words where 'bkoo' like word_like;
```

after changing 'book' to have letters sorted alphabetically

Comment: I would assume that `LIKE` with leading wildcard will fail to meet the request for "the fastest way".

Comment: @RickJames yes, but they also said 0.5 seconds is too slow.  with less than 300k rows, this should significantly outperform that

Comment: sorry but what is point or trick of this?

Comment: @ysth What is the point of adding % instead of just having the words sorted alphabetically? And how will this make the search faster?

Comment: The point here is finding all the words with letters from a given word; you can't do that with just sorted alphabetically.  Faster than what?  You haven't shown what it is that you are doing now; on my slow system, this is much faster than your 0.5 seconds, but ymmv

Answer (score 0):

After pondering the wildcard problem and shortened word problem, here's another partial answer:

Have an `INT UNSIGNED` where the bottom 26 bits represent letters.  There is no good way to use an `INDEX` with such, but it does provide a reasonably fast, space-efficient, way to filter the 267K words.

It does not handle doubled letters (the two Os of BOOK).  But it would filter for "BKO" or "BKO*" about equally.  Handling the extra O would need app code or one of the extra SQL tricks.

(Rob Ruchte's deleted Answer goes into more details.)

Answer (score 0):

Plan 3 -- Pre-build

The table would have 267K rows.  Each row would contain the alphabetized variant of a word, and the all valid words containing those letters:

This approach is a very fast PK lookup:

```
PK      TEXT
art  -- art rat tar smart artwork start ...
bkoo -- book books bookmark bookworm ...
opst -- post spot spotty fencepost ...
abbr -- barb barber abbreviate ...
```

This approach uses FULLTEXT, which is quite fast:

```
TEXT with FULLTEXT index
art rat tar smart artwork start ...
bkoo book books bookmark bookworm ...
opst post spot spotty fencepost ...
abbr barb barber abbreviate ...
```

Since you have the lexicon, the problem now is to generate this 2-column table.

If you want to match "x*" and this is Scrabble, then the existing tiles on the board must either be a single letter or a valid word.  Example: E_CITE -> EXCITE.  By making use of this principle, you can avoid needing strings of 50K words in a row of the table (all words with "E").  (But this is a really messy algorithm.  Is it worth it to get the high speed of FULLEXT?)

There are problems with FULLTEXT -- stopwords, short words, automatic tacking on of endings.